# How to load NSMutableArray from NSDictionary key

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I want to add @"Color", @"size", @"Product_Img" keys' value into different NSMutable array for different keys

**My NSDictionary Structure is....**

```
{
Color =     (
            {
        "color_name" = Red;
        id = 1;
    },
            {
        "color_name" = Black;
        id = 2;
    },
            {
        "color_name" = white;
        id = 3;
    },
            {
        "color_name" = Pink;
        id = 4;
    },
            {
        "color_name" = Green;
        id = 5;
    }
);
"Product_Img" =     (
            {
        "product_image" = "15131445991.jpg";
        "product_image_id" = 94;
    }
);
"product_type" = product;
size =     (
            {
        size = "6 Kg";
    },
            {
        size = "7 Kg";
    },
            {
        size = "8 Kg";
    },
            {
        size = "9 Kg";
    }
);
```

}

and my code is which I try to implement...

viewDidLoad

```
self.arrProductSizeList = [NSMutableArray array];
self.arrProductColorList = [NSMutableArray array];
self.arrProductImageList = [NSMutableArray array];
```

**in configureData method...**

```
[self.arrProductImageList removeAllObjects];
[self.arrProductImageList addObjectsFromArray:[_dictProductDetails objectForKey:@"Product_Img"]];

[self.arrProductColorList removeAllObjects];
[self.arrProductColorList addObjectsFromArray:[_dictProductDetails objectForKey:@"Color"]];

[self.arrProductSizeList removeAllObjects];
[self.arrProductSizeList addObjectsFromArray:[_dictProductDetails objectForKey:@"size"]];
```

NSLog...

```
NSLog(@"Size Array List%@", _arrProductSizeList);
NSLog(@"Color Array List%@", _arrProductColorList);
NSLog(@"Image Array List%@", _arrProductImageList);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: [_dictProductDetails valueForKey:@"Product_Img"]; try this not working than try below code

Comment: And what is not working? What should look like your result?

Comment: I want this...
Size Array List(
        {
        size = "6 ";
    },
        {
        size = "7 ";
    },
        {
        size = "8 ";
    },
        {
        size = "9 ";
    }
)

Comment: Edit your question with the current log that you got (ie your current result), and what you want.

Comment: actually in my project when I load _dictProductDetails dictionary from web service in same viewcontroller then it shown above result and when I load same dictionary from another viewcontroller then I can retrieve all values and keys but problem to load arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try these code:

self.arrProductSizeList = [_dictProductDetails[@"Product_Img"] mutableCopy];

self.arrProductColorList = [_dictProductDetails[@"Color"] mutableCopy];

self.arrProductImageList = [_dictProductDetails[@"size"] mutableCopy];

Comment: Alert message is shown "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recoded"